# Call 5 interface on MS-DOS

Tags: assembly, system-calls, dos

I have a Hello, World program for MS-DOS that uses int 21h to make system calls.

```
mov dx,hello
mov ah,9
int 0x21
mov ah,0
int 0x21
```

"hello" is the address of the string 'hello, world',13,10,'$'.

The program works.

However, when I replace (the first) "int 0x21" with "call 5", the program crashes the computer (i.e. the VirtualBox virtual machine running PTS-DOS). On DOSbox it simply terminates and returns to the command prompt.

I tried using different registers for the address and the call number but always got the same result.

Now I am wondering...

1. Do later versions of DOS not support the CP/M compatibility call 5 interface any more?
2. Do PTS-DOS and the DOS in DOSbox not support call 5?
3. Am I using the interface wrong?
4. Do I have to configure the segment registers first? (I tried setting all segment registers to zero.)

Any ideas?

Update: I accepted the answer because it is correct as per documentation. It still doesn't work but that might be due to my version of DOS or some other problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a version of DOS where you've actually seen a CP/M "call 5" work?  I started with DOS 2.1, but did write some code for 1.1 and the only CP/M compatibility that I saw was in the FCBs.  Of course, I wasn't explicitly looking for it, but I don't recall "call 5" being reported as supported by anybody...

Followup:

The latest PSP definition (as listed on the web, so YMMV) does indeed have the "call 5" interface as supported.  Any true DOS compatible environment *should* support it.

Comment: Should, yes. But I'm not sure which registers to use. Should I use the same ones as for the int calls or the equivalent ones to the 8 bit environment, like cx or cl or ch for c?

Comment: My *guess* is that you'll need to use the 8-bit equiv. registers.  I can't find any definitive information and don't really have time to spin up a test box right now.  It would make the most logical sense that compatibility would be closest with the 8-bit register convention...

Comment: You should use `CL` instead of `AH` for the function number. The other parameters remain the same (see page 7 of [this document](http://www.patersontech.com/dos/Docs/86_dos_prog.pdf)).

Answer (score 5):

DOSBox does not support CALL 5. From its [source code](https://github.com/alunbestor/Boxer/blob/master/DOSBox/src/dos/dos_classes.cpp#L185):

```
// lets hope nobody really uses this address
sSave(sPSP,cpm_entry,RealMake(0xDEAD,0xFFFF));
```

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't expect the old "CALL 5" interface to work with DOSBox, as it only tries to emulate things used in games, and it's very likely no MS-DOS game uses it. This obscure interface exists solely to make it easier to port CP/M programs to MS-DOS, which was essentially just a CP/M clone in its original release. Similarly it wouldn't surprise me if doesn't work in other emulated environments or MS-DOS clones because they don't really need it.

If you're trying to use esoteric things like this you should be using a real version of MS-DOS. You may also need to use a real PC as even VMs like VirtualBox leave out things that aren't needed by the programs people actually use it with.

However even on real MS-DOS on a real PC there's a few limitations when using the CALL 5 compatibility interface:

- As noted by Micheal in a comment, the function number needs to loaded in CL instead of AH.
- CS must point to the PSP. In other words, it only meant to work in .COM programs. An .EXE format executable need to be setup to run like .COM file for it work.
- You can't have HIMEM.SYS or anything else loaded that would enable the A20 line. The far jump instruction at PSP:0005 relies on the 1MB address wrap of an actual 8086 CPU. The low word of the far address at PSP:0006 is set the amount of allocated space in the PSP segment for CP/M compatibility. This means that the far address is usually something like F01D:FEF0 so that it jumps to 0000:00C0 (the INT 30 vector) which then jumps to the actual MS-DOS entry point.
- You can't use DEBUG to run your program. All versions of DEBUG included with MS-DOS since 2 have a bug where they put the wrong address in the PSP.
- You can only use old MS-DOS 1.x functions with function numbers less or equal to 24h.

Comment: Regarding your third bullet: if DOS is loaded high and A20 is enabled, a copy of the far jump at 0000:00C0 should be placed at 10000:00C0 by the memory manager, so that CALL 5 still works.

Comment: @john_e Well, if it's loaded high it would be MS-DOS's responsibility to put that copy there, since it now owns the entire HMA, including 0x1000C0. It appears MS-DOS 6.22 does this, but I don't know how much you can depend on anything else doing that.